# How to create an outline for selected edges and vertices in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a visual effect as in the following drawing:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/52/97003573.png/
[that a selected amount of vertices and edges connecting them will be surrounded by an outline]
I would appreciate any code examples how to do this as I am new to SVG and graphics through javascript in general.
Thanks

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried?

Comment: May also want to ask over at http://groups.google.com/group/d3-js.

Comment: The question is stated clearly in the title and I haven't tried anything yet because I have no clue how to approach this, I am new to D3 and javascript graphics. But thanks for down voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by adding two more sets of very thick 'link' lines, with stroke-linecap values of "round", that can be extended to your selected lines in a similar fashion.

[image: link image]

```
var linkoutline = svg.selectAll(".outline")  
    .data(json.links)
  .enter().append("svg:line")
    .attr("class","outline")
    .style("stroke","red")
    .style("stroke-width",20)
    .style("stroke-linecap","round");
var linkback = svg.selectAll(".backline")
    .data(json.links)
  .enter().append("svg:line")
    .attr("class","backline")
    .style("stroke","white")
    .style("stroke-width",18)
    .style("stroke-linecap","round");
```

See an updated jsfiddle of this at http://jsfiddle.net/s2f8L/8/.  This can be extended to your selected lines in a similar fashion

Comment: Thank you!!! that's a cool hack, extending the stroke line to include the vertices and rounding it.

Answer (score -1):

Is it that hard to do a selectAll based on id or class? You could add shadows using CSS after that as SVG and CSS both offer support for something like this.

Comment: Well if it is that easy then you won't have a problem to demonstrate it on the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s2f8L/, right?